# ("Rid" or "Free") a place ("of" or "from") plastic bottles

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Which is correct?

> Free Hong Kong from plastic bottles
>
> Free Hong Kong of plastic bottles
>
> Rid Hong Kong from plastic bottles
>
> Rid Hong Kong of plastic bottles

Comment: "Rid of" (and "get rid of") and "free of" and "free from" have been the subject of many questions on ELU.  You can look at these and otherwise show the research you've done to try to resolve your questions.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, *from* and *of* have different connotations.

To free HK **from** bottles implies, to me at least, an ongoing situation.  HK will no longer have to worry about/deal with plastic bottles.

To free HK **of** plastic bottles suggests to me more of a clean-up situation.  There are a lot of bottles laying about and someone is going to get rid of them.  It doesn't necessarily address the future situation, just the way it is now based on past usage.

As for *free* versus *rid*, I think they're pretty much equivalent, although *free* does somewhat suggest unshackling, if you will, rather than just getting rid of something.  That is, if plastic bottles are something that have plagued HK then *free* helps imply that.  On the other hand, if there are just a lot of them hanging around, then *rid* might be a better choice.